# Android crash at /system/lib/libart-compiler.so ,libart.so and libc.so

Tags: android-ndk, crash

I always got a crash report from libart-compiler.so in android 8.1.0  and what it's all about?

this bug can happen at any time,anyone knows how to fix it ?

```
--------- beginning of crash
08-03 09:50:00.972  2566  2572 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x9b045e80 in tid 2572 (Jit thread pool), pid 2566 (r.iot.show.core)
08-03 09:50:01.175  3110  3110 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-03 09:50:01.176  3110  3110 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'XHF/XHF_H003/XHF_H003:8.1.0/OPM1.171019.026/20210802-152226:userdebug/test-keys'
08-03 09:50:01.176  3110  3110 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
08-03 09:50:01.176  3110  3110 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
08-03 09:50:01.176  3110  3110 F DEBUG   : pid: 2566, tid: 2572, name: Jit thread pool  >>> com.iflytek.cyber.iot.show.core <<<
08-03 09:50:01.176  3110  3110 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x9b045e80
08-03 09:50:01.176  3110  3110 F DEBUG   :     r0 9b045e80  r1 00000045  r2 fc114286  r3 ffffffff
08-03 09:50:01.176  3110  3110 F DEBUG   :     r4 00000045  r5 9b253c28  r6 9b045e80  r7 9b25b240
08-03 09:50:01.176  3110  3110 F DEBUG   :     r8 9b25e380  r9 9b25e380  sl 00000161  fp 00000000
08-03 09:50:01.176  3110  3110 F DEBUG   :     ip 0000000f  sp 9d9122d0  lr 9dd106db  pc 9dce9cea  cpsr a00d0030
08-03 09:50:01.314  3110  3110 F DEBUG   : 
08-03 09:50:01.314  3110  3110 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
08-03 09:50:01.315  3110  3110 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 000f4cea  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::HEnvironment::RemoveAsUserOfInput(unsigned int) const+41)
08-03 09:50:01.315  3110  3110 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0011b6d7  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::LiveInterval::FindFirstRegisterHint(unsigned int*, art::SsaLivenessAnalysis const&) const+222)
08-03 09:50:01.315  3110  3110 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 001142f3  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::RegisterAllocatorLinearScan::TryAllocateFreeReg(art::LiveInterval*)+334)
08-03 09:50:01.315  3110  3110 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 00113bd5  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::RegisterAllocatorLinearScan::LinearScan()+704)
08-03 09:50:01.315  3110  3110 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 00112c63  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::RegisterAllocatorLinearScan::AllocateRegistersInternal()+334)
08-03 09:50:01.315  3110  3110 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 00112a9d  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::RegisterAllocatorLinearScan::AllocateRegisters()+20)
08-03 09:50:01.315  3110  3110 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 00102489  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::AllocateRegisters(art::HGraph*, art::CodeGenerator*, art::PassObserver*, art::RegisterAllocator::Strategy)+284)
08-03 09:50:01.315  3110  3110 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 00101dc3  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::OptimizingCompiler::TryCompile(art::ArenaAllocator*, art::CodeVectorAllocator*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, unsigned int, art::InvokeType, unsigned short, unsigned int, art::Handle<art::mirror::ClassLoader>, art::DexFile const&, art::Handle<art::mirror::DexCache>, art::ArtMethod*, bool, art::VariableSizedHandleScope*) const+2326)
08-03 09:50:01.316  3110  3110 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 001032fd  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::OptimizingCompiler::JitCompile(art::Thread*, art::jit::JitCodeCache*, art::ArtMethod*, bool, art::jit::JitLogger*)+612)
08-03 09:50:01.316  3110  3110 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 000a09b9  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::jit::JitCompiler::CompileMethod(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, bool)+92)
08-03 09:50:01.316  3110  3110 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 00266a55  /system/lib/libart.so (art::jit::Jit::CompileMethod(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, bool)+288)
08-03 09:50:01.316  3110  3110 F DEBUG   :     #11 pc 0026884b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::jit::JitCompileTask::Run(art::Thread*)+406)
08-03 09:50:01.316  3110  3110 F DEBUG   :     #12 pc 003948b9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Run()+44)
08-03 09:50:01.316  3110  3110 F DEBUG   :     #13 pc 003944eb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Callback(void*)+90)
08-03 09:50:01.316  3110  3110 F DEBUG   :     #14 pc 00047b93  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+22)
08-03 09:50:01.316  3110  3110 F DEBUG   :     #15 pc 0001b057  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)
```

Comment: You found a bug in the JIT compiler. I suggest you report it and ask Google for a possible workaround.

Comment: I have a similar crash using with an Oppo device with Android 11. By any chance did you find out what's the problem? Thank you